# Move branch to a different repository while preserving its commits but aggregating remaining history

Tags: git, copy, repository, branch, git-remote

I have two repositories A and B, which contain different projects. At some point I created a branch 'develop' in repo B and was doing some work there.

```
Repo A master  a-a-a-a

Repo B master  b-b-b-b
                      \
       develop         d-d-d-d-d
```

What I want to do now is to move branch develop from repo B to A, whereas all its commits should be preserved, but the rest of repo B's history should get combined. So at the end it should look like this

```
Repo A master  a-a-a-a
                      \
       develop         d-d-d-d-d

Repo B master  b-b-b-b
                     \
       develop         d-d-d-d-d
```

whereas if I compare the two develop branches they should be similar.
I already achieved to move the branch by

```
- [Repo B] git remote add /url/to/RepoA
- [Repo B] git push RepoA develop
```

However this also includes the entire history of Repo B (b-b-b-b) as well, which I don't want (or actually combined into one commit).

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you did:

```
[Repo B] git push RepoA develop
```

I suppose you get something like:

```
Repo A master  a-a-a-a

repoB/master     b-b-b-b
                        \
         develop         d-d-d-d-d
```

i.e. the two branches `repoA/master` and `repoB/master` are in your repo but are not connected.

Why don't you perform a [rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)?
Use the `-i` option so that you can decide to squash the `b-b-b-b` commits into one commit (I think this is what you want)
The command would be

```
git rebase -i master develop
```

You would then pick the first commit `b` and squash the following ones.
The result should then be:

```
Repo A master  a-a-a-a
                      \
        develop        b'-d'-d'-d'-d'-d'
```

Where `b'` is the commit from the squashing of the 4 commit `b`
and `d'` are the commits resulting from the commit `d`.